# Accessing a website remotely (localhost)

Tags: localhost

I am about to hand in my final year project, i have built a website and my lecturers need to test it. I was wondering what is the best way for them to access it, remotely accessing my localhost or download all files, including the db and setting up the website on their computer.

I am using a Mac.

Comment: Uploading it on a server is by far the easiest. It's the only solution that only requires you to hand your lecturer a url.

Comment: You might ask them how they want the assignment delivered to them.  They may have something specific in mind that wasn't communicated fully.

Comment: @David i have asked, they simply said the way you thinks best

Answer (score 0):

Try using a free web hosting service like [000website](https://www.000webhost.com/cpanel-login) , so you can host your website there and ask the lectures to access it by providing the url of your website

Comment: @user6456767 Did you got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest two options.

1. Try Free Hosting Servers. Lot of them you can find on internet.
2. Try to Set Your computer as a server. Then Forward the Port.[Your Pc Should connect to the internet]. The faculty can check the site when your pc is online.